# ASP.Net Core Check Role Claims With IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I'm using ASP.Net core 3.1.
In my IdentityServer, I add user and role like this

```
public static void EnsureSeedData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

        IdentityResult roleResult;
        //Adding Admin Role
        var roleCheck = RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin").Result;
        if (!roleCheck)
        {

            IdentityRole adminRole = new IdentityRole("Admin");
            //create the roles and seed them to the database
            roleResult = RoleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole).Result;

            RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim("TestClaim1", bool.TrueString)).Wait();
            RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim("TestClaim2", bool.TrueString)).Wait();
            RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim("TestClaim3", bool.FalseString)).Wait();
        }

        var alice = UserManager.FindByNameAsync("alice").Result;
        if (alice == null)
        {
            alice = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = "alice",
                Email = "AliceSmith@email.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
            };
            var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(alice, "Pass123$").Result;
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);
            }

            result = UserManager.AddClaimsAsync(alice, new Claim[]{
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, "Alice Smith"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, "Alice"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.WebSite, "http://alice.com"),
                    }).Result;
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                throw new Exception(result.Errors.First().Description);
            }

            UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(alice, "Admin").Wait();
            //Log.Debug("alice created");
        }
    }
```

In my WebApplication,

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

But in controller `User.Claims` don't have the claims of role,just have claims of user.

So if I want to have the role claims, I should add role claims to user in IdentityServer by providing ProfileService,like this

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var id = context.Subject.FindFirst("sub").Value;
        var user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id).Result;
        var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleObj = _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role).Result;
            var roleClaims = _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(roleObj).Result;
            claims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        }
        
        var nameClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Name);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(nameClaims);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Is this the right way?Or is there other recommended way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To see the roles ,you might need to add this inside AddJwtBearer:

```
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

            };
```

The issue is that IdentityServer and ASP.NET Core does not agree on what the name of the role claim should be, so you need to do a mapping here.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)